# Swift - not convertible to 'NativeObject'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I have the following function, it was working fine in Xcode 6 beta 2

```
func connectPotentially(node: MazeNode)
{
    if node.position != self.position && self.potentialPaths[node.position] == nil {
        self.potentialPaths[node.position] = node
        node.potentialPaths[self.position] = self

        println("Potential path between \(self.position.level)x\(self.position.index) and \(node.position.level)x\(node.position.index)")
    }
}
```

However, in Xcode 6 beta 3 I get following error:
[image]

I have no idea what does it mean. Any thoughts? Maybe a bug?

Here is complete dump of the file:

```
import Foundation


struct MazeNodePosition : Hashable, Equatable {
var level: Int
var index: Int

var hashValue: Int {
    get {
        return level * 0xffff + index
    }
}
}

@infix func ==(left: MazeNodePosition, right: MazeNodePosition) -> Bool
{
    return left.level == right.level && left.index == right.index
}


class MazeNode {

let position: MazeNodePosition

var potentialPaths: Dictionary<MazeNodePosition, MazeNode> = [:]
var paths: Dictionary<MazeNodePosition, MazeNode> = [:]
var visited: Bool = false


init(position: MazeNodePosition)
{
    self.position = position
}


func connectPotentially(node: MazeNode)
{
    if node.position != self.position && self.potentialPaths[node.position] == nil {
        self.potentialPaths[node.position] = node
        node.potentialPaths[self.position] = self

        println("Potential path between \(self.position.level)x\(self.position.index) and \(node.position.level)x\(node.position.index)")
    }
}


func tryConnecting(node: MazeNode) -> Bool
{
    if node.position != self.position && self.paths[node.position] == nil && !node.visited {
        self.paths[node.position] = node
        node.paths[self.position] = self
        node.visited = true
        self.visited = true

        println("Path between \(self.position.level)x\(self.position.index) and \(node.position.level)x\(node.position.index)")

        return true
    }

    return false
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? What's `self.potentialPaths` and what's `node.position`?

Comment: How is the `position` property of the `MazeNode` class declared and how is the `position` property of whatever class `self` is declared?

Comment: I wish I could go back to Xcode 6 beta 2! I'm getting tons of these error all over the place on my hybrid Objective-C Swift project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix in your if statement:

```
self.paths[node.position] == nil
```

should be written as:

```
self.paths[node.position]
```

Comment: Bingo! They really need to fix the error messages. And I have a lot of Swift learning ahead of me

Comment: Make sure to file a radar on anything you feel is incorrect!